# Should I prefer sealed class or Enumeration in Scala?

Tags: scala, enums

I'm trying to implement a [Plurk API](http://www.plurk.com/API/) biding for Scala, but I have a design choice to made.

For example, the gender attribute of a Plurk user could be one of "male", "female", "other".

```
sealed trait Gender
object Male extends Gender
object Female extends Gender
object Others extends Gender
```

The question is should I prefer sealed class/object like above code example, over Enumeration to represent enumeration types?

Because I find that I rarely come across Enumeration when I use other Scala library, and lots of tutorial of Actor use sealed class/object to represent messages for Actor.

So does this means that in Scala, sealed class is a better/conventional choice over Enumeration?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Case classes vs Enumerations in Scala](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1898932/case-classes-vs-enumerations-in-scala)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you don't need to iterate over your objects of Gender or need methods like `next` and `previous`, classes and objects is the right solution.

If you need the features of the "classes and objects" and of "scala.Enumeration" [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4235250/scala-enumerations-with-singleton-objects-as-enumeration-elements-and-a-possibili) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4239594/how-to-access-objects-within-an-object-by-mixing-in-a-trait-with-reflection) question could be of interest to you.

Comment: If you need to iterate on sealed traits you can also use [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13671734/iteration-over-a-sealed-trait-in-scala) macro based solution

Answer (score 9):

Using `Enumeration` is also quite a bit cheaper in terms of class count. In the `Gender` example that does not matter, but it might start to matter if you want to model processor instructions by an enumeration with 100+ elements.

Comment: `Enumeration` would be even nicer if the compiler warned about missing cases like for sealed traits.