# Iteration over a sealed trait in Scala?

Tags: scala, enumeration, scala-macros, sealed

I just wanted to know if it is possible to iterate over a sealed trait in Scala?
If not, why is it not possible? Since the trait is sealed it should be possible no?

What I want to do is something like that:

```
sealed trait ResizedImageKey {

  /**
   * Get the dimensions to use on the resized image associated with this key
   */
  def getDimension(originalDimension: Dimension): Dimension

}

case class Dimension(width: Int,  height: Int)

case object Large extends ResizedImageKey {
  def getDimension(originalDimension: Dimension) = Dimension(1000,1000)
}

case object Medium extends ResizedImageKey{
  def getDimension(originalDimension: Dimension) = Dimension(500,500)
}

case object Small extends ResizedImageKey{
  def getDimension(originalDimension: Dimension) = Dimension(100,100)
}
```

What I want can be done in Java by giving an implementation to the enum values. Is there an equivalent in Scala?

Comment: Isn't [this](https://gist.github.com/ea5e46a2f392204993fa) what you want?

Comment: thanks! Was trying to understand why i couldn't use the case objects ;)

Answer (score 66, accepted):

This is actually in my opinion an appropriate use case for 2.10 macros: you want access to information that you know the compiler has, but isn't exposing, and macros give you a (reasonably) easy way to peek inside. See my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12135229/334519) for a related (but now slightly out-of-date) example, or just use something like this:

```
import language.experimental.macros
import scala.reflect.macros.Context

object SealedExample {
  def values[A]: Set[A] = macro values_impl[A]

  def values_impl[A: c.WeakTypeTag](c: Context) = {
    import c.universe._

    val symbol = weakTypeOf[A].typeSymbol

    if (!symbol.isClass) c.abort(
      c.enclosingPosition,
      "Can only enumerate values of a sealed trait or class."
    ) else if (!symbol.asClass.isSealed) c.abort(
      c.enclosingPosition,
      "Can only enumerate values of a sealed trait or class."
    ) else {
      val children = symbol.asClass.knownDirectSubclasses.toList

      if (!children.forall(_.isModuleClass)) c.abort(
        c.enclosingPosition,
        "All children must be objects."
      ) else c.Expr[Set[A]] {
        def sourceModuleRef(sym: Symbol) = Ident(
          sym.asInstanceOf[
            scala.reflect.internal.Symbols#Symbol
          ].sourceModule.asInstanceOf[Symbol]
        )

        Apply(
          Select(
            reify(Set).tree,
            newTermName("apply")
          ),
          children.map(sourceModuleRef(_))
        )
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Now we can write the following:

```
scala> val keys: Set[ResizedImageKey] = SealedExample.values[ResizedImageKey]
keys: Set[ResizedImageKey] = Set(Large, Medium, Small)
```

And this is all perfectly safe—you'll get a compile-time error if you ask for values of a type that isn't sealed, has non-object children, etc.

Comment: Nice :) It is not as easy as we do in Java but it will get the job done (when i'll use 2.10...)

Comment: Yes, Java's `enum` is arguably less of a train wreck than Scala's `Enumeration`, and is more convenient than sealed traits in this particular respect, but I'd still pick the Scala ADT-like approach over `enum` any day of the week.

Comment: Actually there's a bug in this macro as highlighted by http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18732362/issue-with-using-macros-in-sbt. Its last lines should be replaced with https://gist.github.com/xeno-by/6573434.

Comment: Fixed (finally—my apologies for taking so long to notice the comment). Thanks, Eugene!

Comment: I'm fairly sure the fix didn't need to be so complex. You can just use children.map(c => Ident(c.asClass.module))

Comment: This macro doesn't work for me. I use scala 2.11.2

SealedExample.values[Rank]

I get: type mismatch;  found   : scala.collection.immutable.Set[Product with Serializable with Rank]  required: Set[Rank] Note: Product with Serializable with Rank <: Rank, but trait Set is invariant in type A. You may wish to investigate a wildcard type such as `_ <: Rank`. (SLS 3.2.10) sheet.sc /playground/src line 8 Scala Problem

Comment: With approval from @TravisBrown , I've just packed this answer into a tiny library and published to Bintray.

Source: https://github.com/mrvisser/sealerate
Bintray: https://bintray.com/pellucid/maven/sealerate/view/general

Comment: I know it's been a while since your answer, but is there a possibility to get them in definition order? eg. List(Large, Medium, Small). Changing the result type to List does not cut it.

Comment: @ÁkosVandra my lib mentioned [below](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28569939/1814775) supports returning the implementations in definition order.

Comment: Very very curious about the `sym.asInstanceOf[
            scala.reflect.internal.Symbols#Symbol
          ].sourceModule.asInstanceOf[Symbol]` part? where is it documented?

Comment: @AlejandroNavas This was a long time ago but given the `internal` part I'm fairly confident that the answer to that question is "nowhere".

Comment: @TravisBrown I guess `sym.asInstanceOf[scala.reflect.internal.Symbols#Symbol].sourceModule.asInstanceOf[Symbol]` can be replaced with `sym.owner.info.decl(sym.name.toTermName)`.

Answer (score 8):

The above mentioned solution based on Scala Macros works great. However it does not cases like :

```
sealed trait ImageSize                            
object ImageSize {                                
    case object Small extends ImageSize             
    case object Medium extends ImageSize            
    case object Large extends ImageSize             
    val values = SealedTraitValues.values[ImageSize]
}
```

To allow this, one can use this code:

```
import language.experimental.macros
import scala.reflect.macros.Context

object SealedExample {
    def values[A]: Set[A] = macro values_impl[A]

    def values_impl[A: c.WeakTypeTag](c: Context) = {
        import c.universe._

        val symbol = weakTypeOf[A].typeSymbol

        if (!symbol.isClass) c.abort(
            c.enclosingPosition,
            "Can only enumerate values of a sealed trait or class."
        ) else if (!symbol.asClass.isSealed) c.abort(
            c.enclosingPosition,
            "Can only enumerate values of a sealed trait or class."
        ) else {
            val siblingSubclasses: List[Symbol] = scala.util.Try {
                val enclosingModule = c.enclosingClass.asInstanceOf[ModuleDef]
                enclosingModule.impl.body.filter { x =>
                    scala.util.Try(x.symbol.asModule.moduleClass.asClass.baseClasses.contains(symbol))
                        .getOrElse(false)
                }.map(_.symbol)
            } getOrElse {
                Nil
            }

            val children = symbol.asClass.knownDirectSubclasses.toList ::: siblingSubclasses
            if (!children.forall(x => x.isModuleClass || x.isModule)) c.abort(
                c.enclosingPosition,
                "All children must be objects."
            ) else c.Expr[Set[A]] {
                def sourceModuleRef(sym: Symbol) = Ident(
                    if (sym.isModule) sym else
                        sym.asInstanceOf[
                            scala.reflect.internal.Symbols#Symbol
                            ].sourceModule.asInstanceOf[Symbol]
                )

                Apply(
                    Select(
                        reify(Set).tree,
                        newTermName("apply")
                    ),
                    children.map(sourceModuleRef(_))
                )
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Take a look at @TravisBrown's [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25838411/cant-prove-that-singleton-types-are-singleton-types-while-generating-type-class) As of shapeless 2.1.0-SNAPSHOT the code posted in his question works and produces a `Set` of the enumerated ADT elements which can then be traversed. I will recap his solution here for ease of reference (`fetchAll` is [sort of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43650265/implicit-arguments-how-to-encode-in-function-signature) :-))

```
import shapeless._

  trait AllSingletons[A, C <: Coproduct] {
    def values: List[A]
  }

  object AllSingletons {
    implicit def cnilSingletons[A]: AllSingletons[A, CNil] =
      new AllSingletons[A, CNil] {
        def values = Nil
      }

    implicit def coproductSingletons[A, H <: A, T <: Coproduct](implicit
                                                                tsc: AllSingletons[A, T],
                                                                witness: Witness.Aux[H]
                                                               ): AllSingletons[A, H :+: T] =
      new AllSingletons[A, H :+: T] {
        def values: List[A] = witness.value :: tsc.values
      }
  }

  trait EnumerableAdt[A] {
    def values: Set[A]
  }

  object EnumerableAdt {
    implicit def fromAllSingletons[A, C <: Coproduct](implicit
                                                      gen: Generic.Aux[A, C],
                                                      singletons: AllSingletons[A, C]
                                                     ): EnumerableAdt[A] =
      new EnumerableAdt[A] {
        def values: Set[A] = singletons.values.toSet
      }
  }

  def fetchAll[T](implicit ev: EnumerableAdt[T]):Set[T] = ev.values
```

Comment: I would like to add to your answer that we don't need to implement `EnumerableAdt[T]` for some trait `T` using it implicitly. Everything will work only due to macros generation. I think it's unobvious here.

Answer (score 3):

There's no capability for this natively.   It wouldn't make sense in the more common case, where instead of case objects you had actual classes as subclass of your sealed trait.  It looks like your case might be better handled by an enumeration

```
object ResizedImageKey extends Enumeration {
  type ResizedImageKey = Value
  val Small, Medium, Large = Value
  def getDimension(value:ResizedImageKey):Dimension = 
      value match{
         case Small => Dimension(100, 100)
         case Medium => Dimension(500, 500)
         case Large => Dimension(1000, 1000)

}

println(ResizedImageKey.values.mkString(",") //prints Small,Medium,Large
```

Alternatively, you could create an enumeration on your own, possibly placing it in the companion object for convenience

```
object ResizedImageKey{
  val values = Vector(Small, Medium, Large)
}

println(ResizedImageKey.values.mkString(",") //prints Small,Medium,Large
```

Answer (score 1):

See this [answer in another thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27441788/1148030). The Lloydmetas [Enumeratum library](https://github.com/lloydmeta/enumeratum) provides java Enum like features in [an easily available package](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Ccom.beachape%2Fenumeratum) with relatively little boilerplate.

Answer (score 0):

Something that can also solve the problem is the possibility to add an implicit convertion to add methods to the enum, instead of iteraring over the sealed trait.

```
object SharingPermission extends Enumeration {
  val READ = Value("READ")
  val WRITE = Value("WRITE")
  val MANAGE = Value("MANAGE")
}


/**
 * Permits to extend the enum definition and provide a mapping betweet SharingPermission and ActionType
 * @param permission
 */
class SharingPermissionExtended(permission: SharingPermission.Value) {

  val allowRead: Boolean = permission match {
    case SharingPermission.READ => true
    case SharingPermission.WRITE => true
    case SharingPermission.MANAGE => true
  }
  val allowWrite: Boolean = permission match {
    case SharingPermission.READ => false
    case SharingPermission.WRITE => true
    case SharingPermission.MANAGE => true
  }
  val allowManage: Boolean = permission match {
    case SharingPermission.READ => false
    case SharingPermission.WRITE => false
    case SharingPermission.MANAGE => true
  }

  def allowAction(actionType: ActionType.Value): Boolean = actionType match {
    case ActionType.READ => allowRead
    case ActionType.WRITE => allowWrite
    case ActionType.MANAGE => allowManage
  }

}

object SharingPermissionExtended {
  implicit def conversion(perm: SharingPermission.Value): SharingPermissionExtended = new SharingPermissionExtended(perm)
}
```