# Enumerations -> Sealed trait with a "Value"?

Tags: scala, salat

This question is related to the first one:
[Iteration over a sealed trait in Scala?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13671734/iteration-over-a-sealed-trait-in-scala)

I have the following sealed trait

```
/**
 * @author Sebastien Lorber (<i>lorber.sebastien@gmail.com</i>)
 * Date: 02/12/12 - Time: 17:49
 */
sealed trait ResizedImageKey {

  /**
   * Get the dimensions to use on the resized image associated with this key
   */
  def getDimension(originalDimension: Dimension): Dimension

}

object ResizedImageKey {
  val ALL_KEYS: List[ResizedImageKey] = List(Large,Medium,Small,X2)
}

case class Dimension(width: Int,  height: Int)

case object Large extends ResizedImageKey {
  def getDimension(originalDimension: Dimension) = Dimension(1000,1000)
}

case object Medium extends ResizedImageKey{
  def getDimension(originalDimension: Dimension) = Dimension(500,500)
}

case object Small extends ResizedImageKey{
  def getDimension(originalDimension: Dimension) = Dimension(100,100)
}

case object X2 extends ResizedImageKey{
  def getDimension(originalDimension: Dimension) = Dimension(
    width = originalDimension.width * 2,
    height = originalDimension.height * 2
  )
}
```

This works fine for now.
The matter is that I need to be able to use my ResizedImageKey as a key for a map that will be stored in MongoDB with Salat.

I don't think Salat support "sealed trait convertion" right?
So should  I move to Enumeration, which forces me to do a match / case for the dimensions computations? Or is there any known solution to this problem?
Is it possible to create enumeration Value object without extending Enumeration or something?

Thanks

Comment: You do get a "match is not exhaustive ..." warning as expressed, because the trait is sealed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Salat developer here.

Salat supports case object hierarchies using the `@Salat` annotation.  (I *never* recommend using enums in Scala - they're dreadful.)

Now...  using a case object as the key for a map is actually not something that mongo supports.  All map keys in mongo need to be strings.

So what does this map you're trying to persist look like?

Comment: Thanks. It looks like [ImageResizeKey,FileDescriptor] and I'd prefer keep it like that than doing [String,FileDescriptor] if possible.

Comment: Unfortunately, since MongoDB doesn't support using object as the key to a map, what you can do is persist a list of case classes and convert it to a map as a lazy val inside your case class.  Requiring the keys to maps to be strings is an explicit limitation of MongoDB.