# Scala macros: convert Context#TypeTag to JavaUniverse#TypeTag

Tags: scala, reflection, macros, scala-macros

I want to use macros to generate code which instantiates objects which look like this:

```
import scala.reflect.runtime.universe._
case class Example[T: TypeTag] {
  val tpe = implicitly[TypeTag[T]].tpe
}
```

This, obviously, translates to something like the following:

```
import scala.reflect.runtime.universe._
case class Example[T](implicit ev: TypeTag[T]) {
  val tpe = ev.tpe
}
```

Then if this class is instantiated in regular code Scala compiler provides `TypeTag` instance automatically.

However, I want to generate code which instantiates several instances of this class with different `T`s, where concrete `T`s depend on user input, something like

```
sealed trait Test
case class SubTest1 extends Test
case class SubTest2 extends Test

val examples = generate[Test]
// I want this ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ to expand into this:
val examples = Seq(Example[SubTest1], Example[SubTest2])
```

I [know](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13671734/iteration-over-a-sealed-trait-in-scala) how to get subclasses of a sealed trait, so I can access `c.WeakTypeTag[SubTest1]` and `c.WeakTypeTag[SubTest2]` in macro code. But I do not know how to turn them to `TypeTag`s expected by `Example.apply` method. I thought of using `in()` method which seems to allow transferring `TypeTag`s between universes, but it requires destination mirror, and I don't know how to get runtime mirror at compile time from inside the macro.

Here is the code I have so far (I have added several annotations and extra statements for it to be clearer):

```
object ExampleMacro {
  def collect[T] = macro collect_impl

  def collect_impl[T: c.WeakTypeTag](c: Context): c.Expr[Seq[Example[_]]] = {
    import c.universe._

    val symbol = weakTypeOf[T].typeSymbol

    if (symbol.isClass && symbol.asClass.isTrait && symbol.asClass.isSealed) {
      val children = symbol.asClass.knownDirectSubclasses.toList

      if (!children.forall(c => c.isClass && c.asClass.isCaseClass)) {
        c.abort(c.enclosingPosition, "All children of sealed trait must be case classes")
      }

      val args: List[c.Tree] = children.map { ch: Symbol =>
          val childTpe = c.WeakTypeTag(ch.typeSignature)  // or c.TypeTag(ch.typeSignature)

          val runtimeChildTpe: c.Expr[scala.reflect.runtime.universe.TypeTag[_]] = ???  // What should go here?

          Apply(Select(reify(Example).tree, newTermName("apply")), runtimeChildTpe.tree)
      }

      Apply(Select(reify(Seq).tree, newTermName("apply")), args)
    } else {
      c.abort(c.enclosingPosition, "Can only construct sequence from sealed trait")
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for this:

```
c.reifyType(treeBuild.mkRuntimeUniverseRef, EmptyTree, childTpe)
```

The above code will work assuming `import c.universe._`.

It will create a `Tree` that will eventually evaluate to your desired `scala.reflect.runtime.universe.TypeTag[_]` in runtime.

On second thought, I think manual generation of this tree may not be needed at all. Tree returned from a macro undergoes more typechecking which means that the compiler may be able to fill implicit `TypeTag`s for you. It needs to be tested, though. Try using this:

```
TypeApply(Select(reify(Example).tree, newTermName("apply")), TypeTree().setType(childTpe))
```

Comment: Wow, that's great. I guess I should have tried that first, but I thought that the compiler is not that smart. Apparently, I was wrong) Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to worry about providing the runtime type tag here—the compiler will find it for you (as I see [ghik](https://stackoverflow.com/users/931323/ghik) notes in another answer). The trick is to use `toType` on the child class's type symbol, instead of `typeSignature`:

```
object ExampleMacro {
  def collect[T] = macro collect_impl[T]

  def collect_impl[T: c.WeakTypeTag](c: Context): c.Expr[Seq[Example[_]]] = {
    import c.universe._

    val symbol = weakTypeOf[T].typeSymbol

    if (symbol.isClass && symbol.asClass.isTrait && symbol.asClass.isSealed) {
      val children = symbol.asClass.knownDirectSubclasses.toList

      if (!children.forall(c => c.isClass && c.asClass.isCaseClass)) c.abort(
        c.enclosingPosition,
        "All children of sealed trait must be case classes"
      )

      val args: List[c.Tree] = children.collect {
        case child: TypeSymbol => q"Example[${child.toType}]"
      }

      c.Expr[Seq[Example[_]]](
        Apply(Select(reify(Seq).tree, newTermName("apply")), args)
      ) // or just c.Expr[Seq[Example[_]]](q"Seq(..$args)")
    } else c.abort(
      c.enclosingPosition,
      "Can only construct sequence from sealed trait"
    )
  }
}
```

I've used quasiquotes here for clarity, and since they're [now easily available in 2.10 projects](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/macros/paradise.html#macro_paradise_for_210x), but if you don't want them it would be straightforward to adapt this code to use manual tree construction.

Comment: Thank you very much. Seems that I have tried to outsmart myself. Sadly, IDEA does not support quasiquotes yet( I guess I have to stick with manual tree construction, it is not very hard in this case after all. Honestly, both answers are correct and helpful, so I accept the other one since it was the first.