# Sealed traits in Scala

Tags: scala

Can I get a List of all the case objects that implement a sealed trait? For example.,

I have a sealed trait as below:

```
sealed trait MyTrait
case object A extends MyTrait
case object B extends MyTrait
```

I want to now have something that would give me the List of all the objects that implement this sealed trait?

Comment: Yes, you can. [Macros FTW](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13672520/298389)

Comment: there shouldn't be anything preventing it, all "sealed" does is that you can't inherit outside the document it's in. This doesn't appy to the sub-types

Comment: as a related question, how does the Scala compiler know all sub-classes of a trait since it can provide `non-exhaustive match` warnings?

Comment: That exactly is the purpose of the keyword sealed. It is a hint to the compiler that all the sub classes of the trait are in the same package.