# Abstracting ADT base logic that uses macros into trait

Tags: scala, macros, dry, abstract-data-type, scala-2.11

I recently stumbled on a rather awesome piece of code from Travis Brown @ [Iteration over a sealed trait in Scala?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13671734/iteration-over-a-sealed-trait-in-scala). It turns Scala's `sealed trait` + `case class/object` based ADTs into something that is closer to true enums by allowing enumeration of the ADT "constructors" (in Haskell's terms). So I removed 2 of the 3 deprecation warnings Travis' code was producing and ended up with http://pastebin.com/L1gYGJWh which I then used as follows:

```
sealed trait KeywordType
case object Crime extends KeywordType
case object Gambling extends KeywordType
case object Porn extends KeywordType

object KeywordType {
  /** Maps e.g. "Crime" to Crime */
  def withName(x: String): Option[KeywordType] =
    adt.enumerate[KeywordType].find(_.toString === x)
}
```

However, I quickly needed to reuse the same bit of `withName` logic so I tried to write the following `ADT` base trait:

```
trait ADT[T] {
  def all: Set[T] = enumerate[T]

  def withName(name: String): Option[T] =
    all.find(_.toString === name)
}
```

However, this does not compile giving:

```
Can only enumerate values of a sealed trait or class
```

Although I understand why this error occurs, I do not have a clue as to how to go about telling the type system to "defer" that check until something actually inherits from `ADT`.

Is this even possible with the current macro system in Scala 2.11.2 or do I have to find a (partial) workaround?

Comment: For what it's worth, I just took a shot at solving this in a more principled way with Shapeless and ran into [some weird behavior](http://stackoverflow.com/q/25838411/334519).