# Can't prove that singleton types are singleton types while generating type class instance

Tags: scala, shapeless, implicits, singleton-type

Suppose I've got a type class that proves that all the types in a Shapeless coproduct are singleton types:

```
import shapeless._

trait AllSingletons[A, C <: Coproduct] {
  def values: List[A]
}

object AllSingletons {
  implicit def cnilSingletons[A]: AllSingletons[A, CNil] =
    new AllSingletons[A, CNil] {
      def values = Nil
    }

  implicit def coproductSingletons[A, H <: A, T <: Coproduct](implicit
    tsc: AllSingletons[A, T],
    witness: Witness.Aux[H]
  ): AllSingletons[A, H :+: T] =
    new AllSingletons[A, H :+: T] {
      def values = witness.value :: tsc.values
    }
}
```

We can show that it works with a simple ADT:

```
sealed trait Foo
case object Bar extends Foo
case object Baz extends Foo
```

And then:

```
scala> implicitly[AllSingletons[Foo, Bar.type :+: Baz.type :+: CNil]].values
res0: List[Foo] = List(Bar, Baz)
```

Now we want to combine this with Shapeless's `Generic` mechanism that'll give us a coproduct representation of our ADT:

```
trait EnumerableAdt[A] {
  def values: Set[A]
}

object EnumerableAdt {
  implicit def fromAllSingletons[A, C <: Coproduct](implicit
    gen: Generic.Aux[A, C],
    singletons: AllSingletons[A, C]
  ): EnumerableAdt[A] =
    new EnumerableAdt[A] {
      def values = singletons.values.toSet
    }
}
```

I'd expect `implicitly[EnumerableAdt[Foo]]` to work, but it doesn't. We can use `-Xlog-implicits` to get some information about why:

```
<console>:17: shapeless.this.Witness.apply is not a valid implicit value for
  shapeless.Witness.Aux[Baz.type] because:
Type argument Baz.type is not a singleton type
              implicitly[EnumerableAdt[Foo]]
                        ^
<console>:17: this.AllSingletons.coproductSingletons is not a valid implicit
  value for AllSingletons[Foo,shapeless.:+:[Baz.type,shapeless.CNil]] because:
hasMatchingSymbol reported error: could not find implicit value for parameter
  witness: shapeless.Witness.Aux[Baz.type]
              implicitly[EnumerableAdt[Foo]]
                        ^
<console>:17: this.AllSingletons.coproductSingletons is not a valid implicit
  value for AllSingletons[Foo,this.Repr] because:
hasMatchingSymbol reported error: could not find implicit value for parameter
  tsc: AllSingletons[Foo,shapeless.:+:[Baz.type,shapeless.CNil]]
              implicitly[EnumerableAdt[Foo]]
                        ^
<console>:17: this.EnumerableAdt.fromAllSingletons is not a valid implicit
  value for EnumerableAdt[Foo] because:
hasMatchingSymbol reported error: could not find implicit value for parameter
  singletons: AllSingletons[Foo,C]
              implicitly[EnumerableAdt[Foo]]
                        ^
<console>:17: error: could not find implicit value for parameter e:
  EnumerableAdt[Foo]
              implicitly[EnumerableAdt[Foo]]
                        ^
```

`Baz.type` obviously *is* a singleton type, though. We can try putting the `Witness` instances in scope manually just for fun:

```
implicit val barSingleton = Witness[Bar.type]
implicit val bazSingleton = Witness[Baz.type]
```

And somehow now it works:

```
scala> implicitly[EnumerableAdt[Foo]].values
res1: Set[Foo] = Set(Bar, Baz)
```

I don't understand why these instances would work in this context while the ones generated by the `Witness.apply` macro method (which we used to create them) don't. What's going on here? Is there a convenient workaround that doesn't require us to enumerate the constructors manually?

Comment: I fixed a few bugs in this area recently ... try again with the latest snapshot?

Comment: Hmm, no luck—same result.

Comment: More tweaks pushed today ... third time lucky?

Comment: It works! Thanks, Miles! I'll accept any answer you care to make, of course.

Comment: +1 for `-Xlog-implicits`. I learned about it from this post, and it just helped me to successfully debug a tricky shapeless problem. @TravisBrown: writing stuff about programming that remains relevant for years. :)

Comment: For those ending up at this question because of the behavior provided by `EnumerableAdt`, check out [sealerate](https://github.com/mrvisser/sealerate) - HT @TravisBrown

Answer (score 27, accepted):

This works as written as of the most recent shapeless 2.1.0-SNAPSHOT.