# How to iterate all the product types in a coproduct using shapeless?

Tags: scala, shapeless

Let's say I have a [coproduct](https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless/wiki/Feature-overview:-shapeless-2.0.0#coproducts-and-discriminated-unions) (a sealed trait) such as

```
sealed trait Traity
case object Foo extends Traity
case class Bar() extends Traity
case class Baz() extends Traity
```

Using shapeless, I can apply polymorphic functions to specific instances but what I'd like to do is to apply a zero-parameter (no-instance) polymorphic function to all the products (i.e. case classes and case objects). I have no idea what the syntax would look like, but something conceptually like:

```
object mypoly extends Poly1 {
  implicit def traity[T <: Traity] = when[T]( getClass[T].toString )
}

iterate[Traity](mypoly) // gives List("Foo", "Bar", "Baz")
```

would suit my purposes.

Comment: I can't provide a full answer at the moment, but you could take a look at my question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/25838411/334519) that gives a solution to a similar problem—you'd just need to change the `AllSingletons` type class.

Comment: @TravisBrown thanks! I guess that gets all the instances (`Witness` is grabbing them, right?), but I really only care about the types. Maybe that means my `def coproductX` would just be simpler...

Comment: actually, your question/answer is very useful in its own right!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

For the example use case in your question, this is actually very straightforward:

```
import shapeless._

class NameHelper[A] {
  def apply[C <: Coproduct, K <: HList]()(implicit
    gen: LabelledGeneric.Aux[A, C],
    keys: ops.union.Keys.Aux[C, K],
    toSet: ops.hlist.ToTraversable.Aux[K, Set, Symbol]
  ): Set[String] = toSet(keys()).map(_.name)
}

def names[A] = new NameHelper[A]
```

And then:

```
scala> names[Traity]()
res0: Set[String] = Set(Bar, Baz, Foo)
```

(I'm using a `Set` since the order you're getting is just alphabetical—it's not currently possible to enumerate the constructors in declaration order, although [I'd personally prefer that](https://twitter.com/travisbrown/status/376738546901471232).)

If you'd like a more generic answer, an adaptation of the code in the [question I linked above](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25838411/334519) shouldn't be too bad—I'd be happy to add it here later.

Comment: How would one need to change the code to get back a `Set[A]`, i.e. a set of all available instances?

Comment: @sschaef If you only have case objects the code in the link in the last sentence should work fine now. If you also have case classes with no arguments you'd need to adapt the `AllSingletons` type class.

Comment: Yes, that code works fine, thanks. I just wondered if it is possible to replace `Symbol` with `A` in this answer and immediately get all needed implicits.

Comment: @sschaef No, unfortunately—it takes a little more work to get from the types to instances.

Comment: While the code in the linked question works fine, I just found out that I can't probably use it in my real world application because it has exponential compilation time.

Comment: @sschaef Exponential sounds like a bug—I'd expect quadratic.

Comment: @TravisBrown Is there a way to find instances of a coproduct?

Comment: @flavian In what sense? If `Foo` is a coproduct, then `Coproduct[Foo](x: X)` will only compile if there's an `X` element in `Foo`.

Comment: @TravisBrown A method that given a type would give me all instances of classes descending from the root. In your example you return ```Set[String]```, would it be possible to return ```Set[Foo]```?

Comment: @flavian If those are singleton types, [yes](http://stackoverflow.com/q/25838411/334519). If they're not, you could do it if you had something like a monoid instance or some other way of getting default values.

Comment: @TravisBrown I think I was biased to think Shapeless does the same thing as a reflection scan, but bias aside implicit machinery has little to do what I'm after, apologies for my misunderstanding. It's certainly true my understanding of Shapeless is limited at best.