# Summoning Scala implicits for subclasses of sealed abstract trait

Tags: scala, traits, implicits, subtype

I'm using two Scala libraries that both rely on implicit parameters to supply codecs/marshallers for case classes (the libraries in question are msgpack4s and op-rabbit).  A simplified example follows:

```
sealed abstract trait Event
case class SomeEvent(msg: String) extends Event
case class OtherEvent(code: String) extends Event

// Assume library1 needs Show and library2 needs Printer

trait Show[A] { def show(a: A): String }
trait Printer[A] { def printIt(a: A): Unit }

object ShowInstances {
  implicit val showSomeEvent = new Show[SomeEvent] {
    override def show(a: SomeEvent) =
      s"SomeEvent: ${a.msg}"
  }

  implicit val showOtherEvent = new Show[OtherEvent] {
    override def show(a: OtherEvent) =
      s"OtherEvent: ${a.code}"
  }
}
```

The Printer for the one library can be generic provided there's an implicit Show for the other library available:

```
object PrinterInstances {
  implicit def somePrinter[A: Show]: Printer[A] = new Printer[A] {
    override def printIt(a: A): Unit =
      println(implicitly[Show[A]].show(a))
  }
}
```

I want to provide an API that abstracts over the details of the underlying libraries - callers should only need to pass the case class, internally to the API implementation the relevant implicits should be summoned.

```
object EventHandler {

  private def printEvent[A <: Event](a: A)(implicit printer: Printer[A]): Unit = {
    print("Handling event: ")
    printer.printIt(a)
  }

  def handle(a: Event): Unit = {
    import ShowInstances._
    import PrinterInstances._

    // I'd like to do this:
    //EventHandler.printEvent(a)

    // but I have to do this
    a match {
      case s: SomeEvent => EventHandler.printEvent(s)
      case o: OtherEvent => EventHandler.printEvent(o)
    }
  }
}
```

The comments in EventHandler.handle() method indicate my issue - is there a way to have the compiler select the right implicits for me?.

I suspect the answer is no because at compile time the compiler doesn't know *which* subclass of Event handle() will receive, but I wanted to see if there's another way.  In my actual code, I control & can change the PrinterInstances code, but I can't change the signature of the printEvent method (that's provided by one of the libraries)

*EDIT: I think this is the same as [Provide implicits for all subtypes of sealed type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35943775/provide-implicits-for-all-subtypes-of-sealed-type).  The answer there is nearly 2 years old, I'm wondering if it's still the best approach?

Comment: Brute force approach: replace polymorphic `implicit def somePrinter` with a single `implicit def somePrinter: Printer[Event]` and handle cases inside.

Comment: Our situation is not quite as hopeless as [Provide implicits for all subtypes of sealed type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35943775/provide-implicits-for-all-subtypes-of-sealed-type). In particular, we won't need the raw power of 'shapeless' :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to do the pattern matching somewhere. Do it in the `Show` instance:

```
implicit val showEvent = new Show[Event] {
  def show(a: Event) = a match {
    case SomeEvent(msg) => s"SomeEvent: $msg"
    case OtherEvent(code) => s"OtherEvent: $code"
  }
}
```

If you absolutely need individual instances for `SomeEvent` and `OtherEvent`, you can provide them in a different object so they can be imported separately.

If `Show` is defined to be contravariant (i.e. as `trait Show[-A] { ... }`, with a minus on the generic type) then everything works out of the box and a `Show[Event]` is usable as a `Show[SomeEvent]` (and as a `Show[OtherEvent]` for that matter).

If `Show` is unfortunately not written to be contravariant, then we might have to do a little bit more juggling on our end than we'd like. One thing we can do is declare all of our `SomeEvent` values as simply `Event`s, vis a vis `val fooEvent: Event = SomeEvent("foo")`. Then `fooEvent` will be showable.

In a more extreme version of the above trick, we can actually hide our inheritance hierarchy:

```
sealed trait Event {
  def fold[X]( withSomeEvent: String => X,
               withOtherEvent: String => X ): X
}

object Event {
  private case class SomeEvent(msg: String) extends Event {
    def fold[X]( withSomeEvent: String => X,
                 withOtherEvent: String => X ): X = withSomeEvent(msg)
  }
  private case class OtherEvent(code: String) extends Event {
    def fold[X]( withSomeEvent: String => X,
                 withOtherEvent: String => X ): X = withOtherEvent(code)
  }

  def someEvent(msg: String): Event = SomeEvent(msg)
  def otherEvent(code: String): Event = OtherEvent(code)
}
```

`Event.someEvent` and `Event.otherEvent` allow us to construct values, and `fold` allows us to pattern match.

Comment: Thanks, I ended up using an approach like the first one suggested.  Unfortunately, the actual trait I need to implement has both a method (that takes an instance of the type parameter) and a val that needs to be overridden, so I wasn't able to get it to work exactly like the Show[Event] example above.  I had to explicitly pass my Event to a method that selected the right concrete Codec instance based on the argument & then assign the result to an implicit.  But it still meets the criteria for hiding the codec/marshalling details from the callers which is great.