# Implicit arguments: how to encode in function signature?

Tags: scala, typeclass, shapeless

Following the awesomely enlightening [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25838411/cant-prove-that-singleton-types-are-singleton-types-while-generating-type-class) by @TravisBrown concerning the enumeration of ADTs using shapeless, I am left with the following code snippet:

```
implicitly[EnumerableAdt[Foo]].values
```

I would like to encapsulate this within a method so that I don't have to `.values` after each invocation (It seems a cleaner API to me, that way). *But* I can't seem to get it right. Whenever I try to encapsulate the `implicitly[EnumerableAdt[Foo]]` I get implicit resolution errors.

What I had tried, that made most sense to me, was, for example:

`def imply[T](implicit ev: T):Set[T] = implicitly[EnumerableAdt[T]].values`

certainly without the `ev` made even less sense to me.

I am no expert in type level programming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the definition of [`implicitly[X]`](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.12.2/src/library/scala/Predef.scala#L187), you can see that is requires an implicit argument of type `X` in scope. In your example, you have implicit `ev: T` in scope, which is not enough to call `implicitly[EnumerableAdt[T]]`! Try the following definition instead:

```
def imply[T](implicit ev: EnumerableAdt[T]):Set[T] = ev.values
```