# scala ADTs via sealed traits - is there a way to deserialize from string in a generic fashion

Tags: scala, deserialization, algebraic-data-types

Let's say I have the following trait

```
trait Named {
  def name: String
}
```

and the following Algebraic Data Type

```
sealed trait Animal extends Named

case object Dog extends Animal {
  override val name: String = "dog man"
}

case object Cat extends Animal {
  override val name: String = "cat man"
}

case object Owl extends Animal {
  override val name: String = "I am an owl left in the dark"
}
```

Now, I can deserialize an instance of string into my Animal ADT with the following method.

```
object Animal {

  def apply(name: String): Animal = name match {
    case Dog.name => Dog
    case Cat.name => Cat
  }
}
```

@oxbow_lakes mentions at the end of his [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1899887/101715) that:

> *Can't instantiate easily from persisted value.* This is also true but,
>   except in the case of huge enumerations (for example, all currencies),
>   this doesn't present a huge overhead.

I find that the fact that when you add a new value it needs to be added to the deserialization code explicitly as error prone (I thought that the compiler would warn me of an in-exhaustive match, but take a look at `Owl` above and the `apply` method - there was no warning issued...)

Is there no better way? (If not with the standard scala toolset, a third party one?)

Comment: Todo for me, answer my own question. Found a solution based on two posts:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25838411/cant-prove-that-singleton-types-are-singleton-types-while-generating-type-class 
and 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43650265/implicit-arguments-how-to-encode-in-function-signature
summed up as: http://stackoverflow.com/a/43658710/101715

Answer (score 4):

This problem already solved by `enumeratum` library:
https://github.com/lloydmeta/enumeratum

Your code could be written like this:

```
import enumeratum._
import enumeratum.EnumEntry.Lowercase

sealed trait Animal extends EnumEntry with Lowercase
object Animal extends Enum[Animal] {
  val values = findValues

  case object Dog extends Animal
  case object Cat extends Animal
  case object Owl extends Animal
}

val dogName = Animal.Dog.entryName
val dog = Animal.withNameInsensitive(dogName)
```

Answer (score 3):

One thing you could try is to use reflection to obtain the set of types that extend `Animal`, then use that to create a `Map[String,Animal]` using `name` to lookup object values, then use the map in your `Animal.apply` function.

Refer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12078366/can-i-get-a-compile-time-list-of-all-of-the-case-objects-which-derive-from-a-sea) for more information on obtaining the `Animal` subclasses.

Comment: It would work but I would prefer a way to do so without reflection, if possible

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why would you prefer to avoid reflection? You'd only need to use it once to setup the `String` to `Animal` map, so it wouldn't affect performance, and it wouldn't miss any `Animal` subclasses.

Comment: Obviously your assessment is correct concerning correctness and efficiency. I think that the reason that I would feel better with a compile time solution is that it seems to me that there should be a way to do it. `sealed traits` tell the compiler that there will not be any runtime extension, meaning that all known direct sub types are known in advance. I think that this knowledge should be leverageable. I don't know how to do it, that is why I posted the question. I wonder if what I wish could be done with shapeless, or macros. IMHO, Generally speaking, what can be done in compile time should

Comment: You can use macros with reflection to achieve this at compile-time. This is essentially what the `enumeratum` library does. The downside with macros is that they have to be in a separate (sub)project. That is, if you're using _SBT_, you would create one subproject that defines macros (to query sealed types and generate `set`s containing all subclasses), and another subproject (that depends upon the macro subproject) that contains the case classes and stored lookup map. That shouldn't be too difficult. I've only used the `HList` feature of `Shapeless`, so I can't comment on how that might help.