# Automatic type hints resolving in json4s

Tags: scala, jackson, json4s

Suppose I have a class hierarchy like:

```
trait Event
case class ThisEvent extends Event
case class ThatEvent extends Event
case class AnotherEvent extends Event
```

Currently in my serialization code I have to use this:

```
implicit val formats = new DefaultFormats {
  override val typeHintFieldName = "_t"
  override val typeHints = ShortTypeHints(List(classOf[ThisEvent], classOf[ThatEvent], classOf[AnotherEvent]))
}
```

But I would very much prefer something like this:

```
implicit val formats = new DefaultFormats {
  override val typeHintFieldName = "_t"
  override val typeHints = ShortTypeHints(List(classOf[Event]))
}
```

How would you solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can make `Event` a sealed trait, then you can use the macro explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13671734/iteration-over-a-sealed-trait-in-scala) to iterate over its subclasses, by introducing the `SealedExample` object with the desired helper method.  The example only gets objects that extend the sealed trait, but you could easily modify it to return the `classOf` of every subclass.  Then you can do:

```
override val typeHints = ShortTypeHints(SealedExample.values[Event].toList)
```

Otherwise, unfortunately, there is no native way in Scala to generate a list of the subtypes of a trait at compile time.