# Enforce values a class member can be assigned : Scala

Tags: scala

I intend to restrict the values the string member of my class can take. For eg: for a member named country, only allowable values should be the countries that i have defined like 'US', UK, CN, etc. This constants need to be string constants.

I thought of using Enum, but that does not give me flexibility with the String constants. Or may be i am not aware of how to use it.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

What is the problem with the enum? Seems like a good fit for what you need. Here is an example:

```
object Country extends Enumeration {
  val US = Value("United States")
  val UK = Value("United Kingdom")
}

case class MemberCountry(country: Country.Value)

//example instantiation
MemberCountry(Country.UK)
MemberCountry(Country.withName("United States"))
```

Comment: i want to assign string constant so i should be able to assign a constant Country.US whose value may be "United States"

Comment: @konquestor that's possible with enums, see my updated answer

Answer (score 1):

Enum support is not that good in Scala. First, scala's built-in [Enumeration](http://underscore.io/blog/posts/2014/09/03/enumerations.html) is crap, don't use it.

The common approach for enumerations is sealed trait/class:

```
sealed abstract class Country(val name:String)

object Country {
  case object US extends Country("US")
  case object UK extends Country("UK")
  case object CN extends Country("CN")

  val values = Set(US, UK, CN)
}

Country.values.find(_.name == "US")
```

It has one problem, if you want the list of all possible values, you need to enumerate them yourself (the `values` field in the example above).

However, there are alternatives that solve that problem. 
You can go with macro ([check this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13671734/iteration-over-a-sealed-trait-in-scala)).

Or use third-party [library](https://github.com/lloydmeta/enumeratum).

Answer (score 0):

Enumeration has its strengths and weaknesses in Scala.
You could use any approach highlighted above namely:

- Enumeration subclass
- Use Sealed Trait/Class.

Both approaches have benefits and potential tradeoffs. It might be worth reading through this informative article on this issue:
http://underscore.io/blog/posts/2014/09/03/enumerations.html