# Listing Case Class implementing a Sealed Trait in a Macro

Tags: scala, scala-macros

Let's assume we have a sealed trait and some case class inheriting it:

```
  sealed trait SomeTrait
  final case class ClassA(somevalue : Int) extends SomeTrait
  final case class ClassB(str : String) extends SomeTrait
  (...)
```

Now I want to get all of these case classes extending the trait as a collection. How would I go on about that? In what kind of type would I even need to reference the classes? `weakTypeTag`? Something else?

In a general sense, this is similar to [Travis Brown's answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13672520/1907778) about doing the same with case objects.

My application context: I have a HTTP server and a given file of case classes inheriting a single sealed trait (to be more exact: this hierarchy implements the Command Design Pattern). Now I want to automatically create an endpoint for a HTTP-POST per case class and parse incoming data via `upickle` to the case class corresponding to that endpoint. Programmatrically I do not need the classes / types for anything other.