# Generic sealed trait fromString() method

Tags: scala

Considering the following code :

```
sealed trait Foo {
  def name: String
}

case object FooA extends Foo {
  override val name: String = "a"
}

case object FooB extends Foo {
  override val name: String = "b"
}

object Foo {
  def fromString(name: String): Foo = {
    name match {
     case FooA.name => FooA
     case FooB.name => FooB  
  }
}
```

Can I refactor the fromString() method to avoid having a case per case object instance ? Some more generic code able to enumerate through all Foo instances ?

In my real version, I start to have a lot of case object, and the wall of `case bla.name => bla` is boring me ^^

Thanks :)

Comment: It's possible that the Enumeratum library might help with what you want.

Comment: You can take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13671734/iteration-over-a-sealed-trait-in-scala which has a similar issue

Comment: Yes indeed, it's actually almost a duplicate at this point. Thanks, I failed to find it ^^'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Beachape provide an enum library which can do this for you out of the box:

include this in your `build.sbt`

```
"com.beachape" %% "enumeratum" % "1.5.15"
```

The `Enum` class provided just needs to be extended like so:

```
import enumeratum._

sealed trait Foo

object Foo extends Enum[Foo] {
  case object FooA extends Foo 
  case object FooB extends Foo 
}
```

There is a function called `withName` that will allow you to get the right sealed trait via its string name:

```
Foo.withName("FooA")
```

Answer (score 1):

How about something like this?

```
sealed trait Foo {
  def name: String
}

object Foo {
  case object FooA extends Foo {
    override val name: String = "a"
  }

  case object FooB extends Foo {
    override val name: String = "b"
  }

  val values = Seq(FooA, FooB)

  def withName(name: String): Option[Foo] = {
    values.find(value => value.name.equals(name))
  }
}
```

You can then use the `withName(String)` method to get the corresponding concrete object of type `Foo` as an `Option`:

```
val testFooAName = "a"
val testFooA = Foo.withName(testFooAName) // Will yield Some(FooA)

testFooA match {
    case Some(Foo.FooA) => println("Matched Foo.FooA!")
    case Some(Foo.FooB) => println("Matched Foo.FooB!")
}

val testFooNoneName = "none"
val testFooNone = Foo.withName(testFooNoneName) // Will yield None

Output:
Matched Foo.FooA!
```