# List all case objects extending a trait

Tags: scala

I am trying to replicate `enum.values` using the `trait` and `case object` approach. For example with a regular `enum` you can do:

```
object Permission extends Enumeration {
  type Permission = Value
  val SOME_THINGS, EVERYTHING = Value
}

val allEnumValues: Set[Permission] = Permission.values
```

I need to add logic to each `Permission` to validate if a user should have it, hence I am trying to use the `trait` and `case object` approach. Using this approach the enum becomes something like:

```
trait Permission {
  def name: String
  def appliesTo(user: User): Boolean
}

object Permission {

  def values: Set[Permission] = ... //  Can I use reflection here?

  case object SOME_THINGS extends Permission {
    override def name: String = "SOME_THINGS"
    override def appliesTo(user: User): Boolean = user.isTeamMember
  }

  case object EVERYTHING extends Permission {
    override def name: String = "EVERYTHING"
    override def appliesTo(user: User): Boolean = user.isAdmin
  }
}
```

How can I use reflection to get a list of case objects extending `Permission` and therefore implement my  `def values: Set[Permission]` method?

Comment: Project [enumeratum](https://github.com/lloydmeta/enumeratum) does a similar thing to what you want to achieve, so maybe consider using it instead of creating own solution?

Comment: @KrzysztofAtłasik Looks good thanks for that!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Iteration over a sealed trait in Scala?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13671734/iteration-over-a-sealed-trait-in-scala)