# Get the module symbol, given I have the module class, scala macro

Tags: scala, enums, scala-macros

I'm trying to build a simple typeclass `IsEnum[T]` using a macro.

I use `knownDirectSubclasses` to get all the direct subclasses if `T`, ensure `T` is a sealed trait, and that all subclasses are of case objects (using `subSymbol.asClass.isModuleClass && subSymbol.asClass.isCaseClass`).

Now I'm trying to build a `Seq` with the case objects referred by the subclasses.

It's working, using a workaround:

```
  Ident(subSymbol.asInstanceOf[scala.reflect.internal.Symbols#Symbol].sourceModule.asInstanceOf[Symbol])
```

But I copied that from some other [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13671734/iteration-over-a-sealed-trait-in-scala), yet it seems hacky and wrong. Why does that work? and is there a cleaner way to achieve that?

Comment: If you cannot use enumeratum (which provides `Enum` type class for its own types) I implemented `Enum` type class which works for: enumeratum, enumaration, Java enums and sealed hierarchies of case objects - https://github.com/scalalandio/enumz . You can take a look at macros there if you are interested.

Comment: @MateuszKubuszok I guess manual parsing/typechecking can be replaced with `Ident(subSymbol.owner.info.decl(subSymbol.name.toTermName))`.

Comment: Good to know, thanks!

Comment: The shortest is `Ident(subSymbol.asClass.module)`.

Answer (score 3):

In 2.13 you can materialize `scala.ValueOf`

```
val instanceTree = c.inferImplicitValue(appliedType(typeOf[ValueOf[_]].typeConstructor, subSymbol.asClass.toType))
q"$instanceTree.value"
```

Tree will be different

```
sealed trait A
object A {
  case object B extends A
  case object C extends A
}
```

```
//scalac: Seq(new scala.ValueOf(A.this.B).value, new scala.ValueOf(A.this.C).value)
```

but at runtime it's still `Seq(B, C)`.

In 2.12 `shapeless.Witness` can be used instead of `ValueOf`

```
val instanceTree = c.inferImplicitValue(appliedType(typeOf[Witness.Aux[_]].typeConstructor, subSymbol.asClass.toType))
q"$instanceTree.value"
```

```
//scalac: Seq(Witness.mkWitness[App.A.B.type](A.this.B.asInstanceOf[App.A.B.type]).value, Witness.mkWitness[App.A.C.type](A.this.C.asInstanceOf[App.A.C.type]).value)
```

```
libraryDependencies += "com.chuusai" %% "shapeless" % "2.4.0-M1" // in 2.3.3 it doesn't work
```

---

In Shapeless they use kind of

```
subSymbol.asClass.toType match {
  case ref @ TypeRef(_, sym, _) if sym.isModuleClass => mkAttributedQualifier(ref)
}
```

https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless/blob/master/core/src/main/scala/shapeless/singletons.scala#L230

or in our case simply

```
mkAttributedQualifier(subSymbol.asClass.toType)
```

but their `mkAttributedQualifier` also uses downcasting to compiler internals and the tree obtained is like `Seq(A.this.B, A.this.C)`.

Also

```
Ident(subSymbol.companionSymbol)
```

seems to work (tree is `Seq(B, C)`) but `.companionSymbol` is deprecated (in scaladocs it's written "may return unexpected results for module classes" i.e. for objects).

Following approach similar to the one used by **@MateuszKubuszok** in his library [enumz](https://github.com/scalalandio/enumz) you can try also

```
val objectName = symbol.fullName
c.typecheck(c.parse(s"$objectName"))
```

and the tree is `Seq(App.A.B, App.A.C)`.

Finally, if you're interested in the tree `Seq(B, C)` (and not some more complicated tree) it seems you can replace

```
Ident(subSymbol.asInstanceOf[scala.reflect.internal.Symbols#Symbol].sourceModule.asInstanceOf[Symbol/*ModuleSymbol*/])
```

with more conventional

```
Ident(subSymbol.owner.info.decl(subSymbol.name.toTermName)/*.asModule*/)
```

or **(the shortest option)**

```
Ident(subSymbol.asClass.module/*.asModule*/)
```