# Invoke private method in arbitrary scala object

Tags: scala, reflection, scala-reflect

Let's say I have a Scala object:

```scala
object SomeObject {
  private def someMethod(msg: String): Unit = println(msg)
}
```

I can invoke `someMethod` with the following code:

```scala
import scala.reflect.runtime.{universe => ru}
import scala.reflect.ClassTag

def invokeObjectPrivateMethod[R](methodName: String, args: AnyRef*): R = {
  val rm = ru.runtimeMirror(getClass.getClassLoader)
  val instanceMirror = rm.reflect(SomeObject)
  val methodSymbol = ru.typeOf[SomeObject.type].decl(ru.TermName(methodName)).asMethod
  val method = instanceMirror.reflectMethod(methodSymbol)
  method(args: _*).asInstanceOf[R]
}
invokeObjectPrivateMethod("someMethod", "it works")
```

But above I've hardcoded `SomeObject` into the function. What I'd really like is to pass an arbitrary object name/classtag/whatever so I can invoke a private function generically in ANY object.

These attempts have NOT worked:

```scala
// With explicit ClassTag parameter
def invokeObjectPrivateMethod2[R](classTag: ClassTag[_], methodName: String, args: AnyRef*): R = {
  val rm = ru.runtimeMirror(getClass.getClassLoader)
  val instanceMirror = rm.reflect(classTag)
  val methodSymbol = ru.typeOf[classTag.type].decl(ru.TermName(methodName)).asMethod
  val method = instanceMirror.reflectMethod(methodSymbol)
  method(args: _*).asInstanceOf[R]
}
// This fails at runtime with: `scala.ScalaReflectionException: <none> is not a method`
invokeObjectPrivateMethod2[Unit](ClassTag(SomeObject.getClass), "someMethod", "it doesn't work")

// With implicit ClassTag/TypeTag
def invokeObjectPrivateMethod3[T: ClassTag, S: ru.TypeTag, R](methodName: String, args: AnyRef*)(implicit ct: ClassTag[T]): R = {
  val rm = ru.runtimeMirror(getClass.getClassLoader)
  val instanceMirror = rm.reflect(ct)
  val methodSymbol = ru.typeOf[S].decl(ru.TermName(methodName)).asMethod
  val method = instanceMirror.reflectMethod(methodSymbol)
  method(args: _*).asInstanceOf[R]
}
// This fails at compile time: `not found: type SomeObject`
invokeObjectPrivateMethod3[SomeObject, SomeObject, Unit]("someMethod", "it also doesn't work")
```

I'm somewhat out of my depth, so what I'm trying with the 3rd option might not even make sense.

Thanks!

Comment: Are you really sure that you need to do this? Why you want to access private values of any arbitrary object?

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez it's more of a curiosity now, but it would be for testing. In my case, we have some objects where methods must be kept private for security reasons. Some methods may load a file from disk, but for unit testing we'd like to be able to swap the default out with a test file (in production, we can block the use of reflection so users can't do the same thing). This approach would avoid a potentially large refactoring.

Comment: Java reflection is a lot easier than Scala reflection. Might Java reflection be an easier path here?

Comment: @SethTisue but then we should be ready to work with strings like `str.replace('.', '$')` or vice versa, `str + "$"` etc.

Comment: @SethTisue My understanding was that it didn't work with Java because you don't have an instance of the object to pass to `invoke(instance, "arg")`. Passing `null` doesn't work.

Comment: @ishovelwell The instance of object is in static field `MODULE$`. I added Java reflection code to my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following if you have `String` of object name

```
def invokeObjectPrivateMethod[R](objectName: String, methodName: String, args: AnyRef*): R = {
  val rm = scala.reflect.runtime.currentMirror
  val moduleSymbol = rm.staticModule(objectName)
  val classSymbol = moduleSymbol.moduleClass.asClass
  val moduleMirror = rm.reflectModule(moduleSymbol)
  val objectInstance = moduleMirror.instance
  val objectType = classSymbol.toType
  val methodSymbol = objectType.decl(ru.TermName(methodName)).asMethod
  val instanceMirror = rm.reflect(objectInstance)
  val methodMirror = instanceMirror.reflectMethod(methodSymbol)
  methodMirror(args: _*).asInstanceOf[R]
}

invokeObjectPrivateMethod("com.example.App.SomeObject", "someMethod", "it works") //it works
```

or if you have object `ClassTag`

```
def invokeObjectPrivateMethod[R](classTag: ClassTag[_], methodName: String, args: AnyRef*): R = {
  val rm = scala.reflect.runtime.currentMirror
  val clazz = classTag.runtimeClass
  val classSymbol = rm.classSymbol(clazz)
  val moduleSymbol = classSymbol.owner.info.decl(classSymbol.name.toTermName).asModule //see (*)
  val moduleMirror = rm.reflectModule(moduleSymbol)
  val objectInstance = moduleMirror.instance
  val objectType = classSymbol.toType
  val methodSymbol = objectType.decl(ru.TermName(methodName)).asMethod
  val instanceMirror = rm.reflect(objectInstance)
  val methodMirror = instanceMirror.reflectMethod(methodSymbol)
  methodMirror(args: _*).asInstanceOf[R]
}
invokeObjectPrivateMethod(classTag[SomeObject.type], "someMethod", "it works") //it works
```

or if you have object `TypeTag`

```
def invokeObjectPrivateMethod[R](typeTag: TypeTag[_], methodName: String, args: AnyRef*): R = {
  val rm = scala.reflect.runtime.currentMirror
  val objectType = typeTag.tpe
  val clazz = rm.runtimeClass(objectType) // see (**)
  val classSymbol = rm.classSymbol(clazz)
  val moduleSymbol = classSymbol.owner.info.decl(classSymbol.name.toTermName).asModule // see (*)
  val moduleMirror = rm.reflectModule(moduleSymbol)
  val objectInstance = moduleMirror.instance
  val methodSymbol = objectType.decl(ru.TermName(methodName)).asMethod
  val instanceMirror = rm.reflect(objectInstance)
  val methodMirror = instanceMirror.reflectMethod(methodSymbol)
  methodMirror(args: _*).asInstanceOf[R]
}

invokeObjectPrivateMethod(typeTag[SomeObject.type], "someMethod", "it works") //it works
```

or if you have object `Class`

```
def invokeObjectPrivateMethod[R](clazz: Class[_], methodName: String, args: AnyRef*): R = {
  val rm = scala.reflect.runtime.currentMirror
  val classSymbol =  rm.classSymbol(clazz)
  val moduleSymbol = classSymbol.owner.info.decl(classSymbol.name.toTermName).asModule //see (*)
  val moduleMirror = rm.reflectModule(moduleSymbol)
  val objectInstance = moduleMirror.instance
  val objectType = classSymbol.toType
  val methodSymbol = objectType.decl(ru.TermName(methodName)).asMethod
  val instanceMirror = rm.reflect(objectInstance)
  val methodMirror = instanceMirror.reflectMethod(methodSymbol)
  methodMirror(args: _*).asInstanceOf[R]
}

invokeObjectPrivateMethod(SomeObject.getClass, "someMethod", "it works") //it works
```

or if you have object `Type`

```
def invokeObjectPrivateMethod[R](typ: Type, methodName: String, args: AnyRef*): R = {
  val rm = scala.reflect.runtime.currentMirror
  val classSymbol =  typ.typeSymbol.asClass
  val moduleSymbol = classSymbol.owner.info.decl(classSymbol.name.toTermName).asModule //see (*)
  val moduleMirror = rm.reflectModule(moduleSymbol)
  val objectInstance = moduleMirror.instance
  val methodSymbol = typ.decl(ru.TermName(methodName)).asMethod
  val instanceMirror = rm.reflect(objectInstance)
  val methodMirror = instanceMirror.reflectMethod(methodSymbol)
  methodMirror(args: _*).asInstanceOf[R]
}

invokeObjectPrivateMethod(typeOf[SomeObject.type], "someMethod", "it works") //it works
```

(*) [Get the module symbol, given I have the module class, scala macro](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64121612/get-the-module-symbol-given-i-have-the-module-class-scala-macro)

(**) [How to get ClassTag form TypeTag, or both at same time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18729321/how-to-get-classtag-form-typetag-or-both-at-same-time)

I assume that the method didn't have overloaded versions, otherwise you should work with `typ.decl(...).alternatives.find(...).get.asMethod` or `typ.decl(...).alternatives.head.asMethod`.

Using Java reflection

```
def invokeObjectPrivateMethod[R](packageName: String, objectName: String, methodName: String, args: AnyRef*): R = {
  val javaClassName = s"$packageName.${objectName.replace('.', '$')}$$"
  val clazz = Class.forName(javaClassName)
  val method = clazz.getDeclaredMethods.find(_.getName == methodName).get
  method.setAccessible(true)
  val field = clazz.getField("MODULE$")
  val instance = field.get(null) // null because field is static
  method.invoke(instance, args: _*).asInstanceOf[R]
}

invokeObjectPrivateMethod("com.example", "App.SomeObject", "someMethod", "it works") //it works
```

Using Java method handles

```
def invokeObjectPrivateMethod[R](packageName: String, objectName: String, methodName: String, args: AnyRef*): R = {
  val javaClassName = s"$packageName.${objectName.replace('.', '$')}$$"
  val clazz = Class.forName(javaClassName)
  val lookup = MethodHandles.lookup
  val field = clazz.getField("MODULE$")
  val fieldMethodHandle = lookup.unreflectGetter(field)
  val instance = fieldMethodHandle.invokeWithArguments()
  val method = clazz.getDeclaredMethods.find(_.getName == methodName).get
  method.setAccessible(true)
  val methodHandle = lookup.unreflect(method)
  methodHandle.invokeWithArguments(instance +: args : _*).asInstanceOf[R]
}

invokeObjectPrivateMethod("com.example", "App.SomeObject", "someMethod", "it works") //it works
```

Comment: Works! Thanks for the exhaustive answer