# Using ClassSymbol in a quasiquote

Tags: scala, metaprogramming, abstract-syntax-tree, scala-macros, scala-quasiquotes

I have a `ClassSymbol` and want to generate a zero-argument method throwing `???`. Here are my attempts:

Assume that `object Test` is the type we have `ClassSymbol` of.

**I.**

```
val sym = //the ClassSymbol
val tpe = tq"$sym.type"
q"def foo(): $tpe = ???"
```

**Result**:

```
[error]  stable identifier required, but Test.type found.
```

**II.**

```
val sym = //the ClassSymbol
val tpe = tq"${sym.name}.type"
q"def foo(): $tpe = ???"
```

**Result**:

```
[error]  found   : c.universe.TypeName
[error]  required: c.universe.TermName
[error]         val tpe = tq"${sym.name}.type"
```

**III.**

```
val sym = //the ClassSymbol
val tpe = tq"${TermName(sym.name.toString)}.type"
q"def foo(): $tpe = ???"
```

**Result**:

```
Compiles successfully
```

So I ended up using the method **III** which looks pretty scary.

Is there a "native" way to use `ClassSymbol` in a quasiquote?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can save your approach II

```
val tpe = tq"${sym.name.toTermName}.type"
```

This is similar to III but without manual handling strings.

Also don't forget that besides quasiquotes you can always build trees with manual parsing

```
val tree = tb.parse(s"def foo(): ${sym.name}.type = ???") // for macros c.parse instead of tb.parse
```

Regarding the "native" way, now it's better to use a `ModuleSymbol`

```
val sym = rm.moduleSymbol(Test.getClass)
```

or

```
val sym = typeOf[Test.type].termSymbol.asModule
```

rather than `ClassSymbol`

```
val sym0 = rm.classSymbol(Test.getClass)
```

or

```
val sym0 = typeOf[Test.type].typeSymbol.asClass
```

Testing:

```
val tpe = tq"$sym.type"
val tree = q"def foo(): $tpe = ???"
tb.typecheck(tree) // no exception
```

I used runtime reflection but for macros it's similar.

If you already have a `ClassSymbol` it can be converted to a `ModuleSymbol`

```
val sym = sym0.companionSymbol // not sym0.companion but .companionSymbol is deprecated
```

or

```
val sym = sym0.asInstanceOf[scala.reflect.internal.Symbols#ClassSymbol].sourceModule.asInstanceOf[ModuleSymbol]
```

or

```
val sym = sym0.owner.info.decl(sym0.name.toTermName)
```

[Get the module symbol, given I have the module class, scala macro](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64121612/get-the-module-symbol-given-i-have-the-module-class-scala-macro)

Comment: Thanks. I guess that when using an arbitrary class type it should be tested for being a `Module` (`isModule`) before insterting the `.type` suffix.