# Scala Refer to a type parameter

Tags: scala

Is there any way to refer to a type parameter?

For example i have wantd to make a class that gets Sub class of Enumeration and than use him:
example of what i wanted :

```
class MyEnum1 extends Enumeration{
    type MyEnum=Value
    a1=Value("A1")
    b1=Value("B1")
}

class MyEnum2 extends Enumeration{
    type MyEnum=Value
    a2=Value("A2")
    b2=Value("B2")
}


class UseType[T:<Enumeration]{
    val values=T.values
}
```

Do you know how can i do it?

Comment: Don't you messing instances (and their data) with class (blueprint) put alone?

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to work at the object level, not the type level, and pass an instance (which can be a singleton object) into your class:

```
object MyEnum1 extends Enumeration {
  type MyEnum1 = Value
  val a1 = Value("A1")
  val b1 = Value("B1")
}

object MyEnum2 extends Enumeration {
  type MyEnum2 = Value
  val a2 = Value("A2")
  val b2 = Value("B2")
}

class UseType[T <: Enumeration](val t: T) {
  println(t.values)
}

new UseType(MyEnum1)              //> MyEnum1.ValueSet(A1, B1)
new UseType(MyEnum2)              //> MyEnum2.ValueSet(A2, B2)
```

I'm not quite sure why you would want to do this, though - can you explain what you are trying to achieve? You might need to give `MyEnum1` and `MyEnum2` an additional shared trait in order for them to work interchangeably in your code?

See also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11067396/understanding-scala-enumerations) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4236251/should-i-prefer-sealed-class-or-enumeration-in-scala), and also [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1898932/case-classes-vs-enumerations-in-scala) - depending on your use case, you might prefer to use sealed case classes.

Comment: why did you wrote [T <: Enumeration](**val** t: T)

when i was tryng to write it without val it didnt compile.
Any idea?

Comment: I'm not sure why I added the `val` ! - it's only needed if you want to refer to `t` as a property of the `UseType`, e.g. `UseType(MyEnum1).t`